# Loops in RxJS Observable don't stop after calling complete or error

Tags: javascript, rxjs-observables

When calling `observer.complete()` or `observer.error()` an observer stops sending data and is considered done. However, If there is a for loop in the observer, the loop will continue running even after `observer.complete()` is called. Can someone explain to me this behaviour? I expect that the loop would be cut short. The current behaviour means that an interval or a while loop will forever run in an `Observable` unless I unsubscribe in the code.

In the below snippet I added a `console.log` to see if the log will be called after `observer.complete()`.

```
    const testObservable = new Observable( observer => {
    for (let count = 0; count < 11; count++){
      observer.next(count);
      if (count > 5) {
        observer.complete()
        console.log("test")
      }
      if (count > 7) {
        observer.error(Error("This is an error"))
      }
    }}
  );

let firstObservable = testObservable.subscribe(
    next => {console.log(next)},
    error => { alert(error.message)},
    () => {console.log("complete")}
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a responsibility of the create function to properly destroy resources. In your case there could be simply `return` statement after `observer.complete()`.

But in general if needed, the create function should return the teardown function (TeardownLogic), that is called when the observable is finalised.

```
new Observable( observer => {
  // observable logic, e.g. ajax request
  return () => {
    // teardown function, e.g. cancel ajax request
  };
});
```

Observable just ignore future calls of `next(...)`, `complete()` and `error(...)` once the observable is finalized. It means that `complete()` or `error(...)` function was called internally or the observable was unsubscribed externally.

```
new Observable( observer => {
  observer.next('a');
  observer.complete();
  // next calls will be ignored
  observer.next('b');
});
```

```
const observable = new Observable( observer => {
  setTimeout(
    () => observer.next('a'), // this will be ignored due to unsubscribe
    10
  );
});
const subscription = observable.subscribe(...);
subscription.unsubscribe();
```